# how to download file from pdf file generator into client local in Go and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, go, pdf

i create a service to generate pdf file with `go-wkhtmltopdf`

this is the function

```
func Pdf() func(c *gin.Context) {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        // download wkhtmltopdf and set that wkhtmltopdf on below
        wkhtmltopdf.SetPath("/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf")
        type ReqHtml struct {
            Html string `json:"html"`
        }
        var html ReqHtml
        _ = c.BindJSON(&html)

        pdfg, err := wkhtmltopdf.NewPDFGenerator()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        page := wkhtmltopdf.NewPageReader(strings.NewReader(html.Html))
        pdfg.Orientation.Set(wkhtmltopdf.OrientationPortrait)
        page.FooterRight.Set("[page]")
        page.FooterFontSize.Set(10)

        pdfg.AddPage(page)

        err = pdfg.Create()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        err = pdfg.WriteFile("./myPdf.pdf")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

    }
}
```

that Writefile writes file into my root folder server, how to make the client download it?

let say i have `<button> download file </button>`

should I give a response to the client with the buffer of that result? or what?

Comment: "should I give a response to the client with the buffer of that result?" yes, of course.

Comment: @Volker should I just give the object with like this {. buffer: "this issues buffer"} or any example?? :)

Comment: What you should do depends on your business requirements. What do you WANT to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just send the buffer to the client and use this function to download the file (React sample code):

```
prepareDocForDownload = result => {
    const length = Object.entries(result.data).length;
    let bytes = new Uint8Array(length);

    for (let i=0; i<length; i++) {
      bytes[i] = result.data[i];
    }

    const file = new Blob(
      [bytes.buffer],
      {type: 'application/pdf'});

    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = fileURL;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
  };
```

Comment: is the result.data for the buffer ???, can u give me example of the object result ?

Comment: @WeqIou It looks like this in chrome's developer console: {"data":{"0":80,"1":75,"2":48, ...........}}

Comment: the buffer I get something like this : `JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0bGUgKP7/KQovQ3JlYXRvciAo/v8AdwBrAGgAdABtAGwAdABvAHAAZABmACAAMAAuADEAMgAuADUpCi9Qcm9kdWNlciAo/v8AUQB0ACAANAAuADgALgA3KQovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlIChEOjIwMjAwMjEyMTkxMzI0KzA3JzAwJykKPj4KZW5kb2JqCjMgMCBvYmoKPDwKL1R5cGUgL0V4dEdTdGF0ZQovU0EgdHJ1ZQovU00gMC4wMgovY2EgMS4wCi9DQSAxLjAKL0FJUyBmYWxzZQovU01hc2sgL05vbmU`

Comment: @WeqIou This looks like a base64 encoded string. Try to convert it to byte from the client-side. Replace the first 5 lines of the function with this: const bytes = new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes("YOUR STRING");

Comment: is file result like this : `Blob {
  [Symbol(type)]: 'application/pdf',
  [Symbol(buffer)]: <Buffer 4a 00 56 00 42 00 45 00 52 00 69 00 30 00 78 00 4c 00 6a 00 51 00 4b 00 4d 00 53 00 41 00 77 00 49 00 47 00 39 00 69 00 61 00 67 00 6f 00 38 00 50 00 ... 26128 more bytes>
}`

Comment: @WeqIou Those numbers are bytes. So you need to fill the "bytes" array with these numbers. `bytes[0] = parseInt('4a', 16); bytes[1] = parseInt('00', 16); bytes[2] = parseInt('56', 16);` and so on. (Obviously you need to do this inside a loop :)